# Invite code to show form and login button

Tags: php, jquery, sql, wordpress, forms

What I want to try and make is an landing page with this functionality that includes an input for a invite code for users use, which once successful allows you to register or log in.

But I have no idea how I would make a scripts in MySQL and PHP for the invite code, which is the main bit I need help with.

What I want to happen ideally is the when the input is filled in successfully - a registration form appears (using jQuery) and a login button is enabled on the same page.

I know this isn't a a lot to go on but any help/ fiddles or idea would be greatly appreciated

Sam

Answer (score 0):

after filling the correct code. put this jquery:

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   //if correct code THEN $('login_div').show() ;

 }) ;
```

HTML:

```
<form id="login_div" style="display:none"> 

   <input type="text" name="txt_name" />
   <input type="text" name="txt_pass" />      

</form>
```